# Icons on CMFCOutlookBar

Tags: mfc

I'm using CMFCOutlookBar from the Feature Pack, and I'm trying to put an icon on the "button" of the tabbed pane - the thing that slides up and down in the bar, when you select a pane.  The pane API includes a "SetIcon" function, but this doesn't do anything as far as I can tell.  Neither does the "SetTabHicon" function of the bar.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if only this is enough, but you should call SetMode2003 on your CMFCOutlookBar and set icons using SetImageList.

Take a look at OutlookDemo project in Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack Samples. They use two bars, one with icons and one without, so you can compare code.

Answer (score 0):

See my posting [CMFCOutlookBarPane icons disappearing when dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062088/cmfcoutlookbarpane-icons-disappearing-when-dragging)

Maybe I have a partial solution to your problem